# Spring JPA solution to Thymeleaf returning Strings instead of List<Object>

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I have created a Thymeleaf form and am attempting to map a field with multiple inputs to a List in a OneToMany entity. However, I keep getting the below error:

```
default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'project.model.Prop' for property 'propList[0]'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'project.model.Prop' for property 'propList[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

Many others on this site have faced a similar error, and I have found someone facing an almost identical issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51024877/thymeleaf-returning-a-string-array-instead-of-listobject). However, for that post, one answer provides a non-JPA solution. At the same time, the answer says that there is a JPA way to handle the issue, but no additional details are provided.

Can anyone explain how to resolve that post's situation with JPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve the issue with the Spring Data JPA, you must bring the `List<Prop>` List-object from its repository. Then, you would not need to make your own custom converter to solve the issue.